# Convert pinescript to v4 & stop it repainting

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I have been doing very simple changes to pinescript so far, I am now trying to amend a script which I am using from repainting, as it is an older script I am also trying to convert it to Pinescript V4, I have amended the lines of code which appear to be required for V4 and have also added non painting security function, unfortunately I cannot test it due to receiving undeclared identifier errors:

- line 14: Undeclared identifier 'haopen';
- line 16: Undeclared identifier 'haopen';
- line 17: Undeclared identifier 'haopen';
- line 19: Undeclared identifier 'heikUp';
- line 20: Undeclared identifier 'heikDown'

Do I need to declare these differently on V4?
I would appreciate if someone can please advise where I am going wrong with my amendments to this script?  Is the repainting function I have added suitable to prevent the script from repainting?  Thanks

```
//Heikin Ashi Triangles
// @version=4
study(title="HeikinAshiTriangles", shorttitle="HATriangles", overlay=true)
as = input(true, title="Show Heikin Ashi Triangles at Top and Bottom of Screen?")
useCurrentRes = input(true, title="Use Current Chart Resolution?")
res = input(title="Use Different Timeframe? Uncheck Box Above", type=input.resolution, defval="60")

// Create non-repainting security function
rp_security(_symbol, _res, _src) => security(_symbol, _res, _src[barstate.isrealtime ? 1 : 0])

haclose = ((open + high + low + close)/4) //[smoothing]
haopen = na(haopen[1]) ? (open + close)/2 : (haopen[1] + haclose[1]) / 2

heikUp = haclose > haopen
heikDown = haclose <= haopen

hU = rp_security(syminfo.tickerid, res, heikUp)
hD = rp_security(syminfo.tickerid, res, heikDown)

plotshape(as and hU ? hU and barstate.isconfirmed: na, title="Heikin Ashi Triangles",style=shape.triangleup, location=location.bottom, color=color.lime, transp=0, offset=0)
plotshape(as and hD ? hD and barstate.isconfirmed: na, title="Heikin Ashi Triangles",style=shape.triangledown, location=location.top, color=color.red, transp=0, offset=0)

barcolor(hU ? #05ff9b : na)
barcolor(hD ? #ff0583 : na) 

alertcondition(hU, "Buy")
alertcondition(hD, "Sell")
```

Answer (score 0):

1. use the var keyword, for every error you see like this for all the variables on which you have the error

```
var float haopen = 0.
haopen := na(haopen[1]) ? (open + close)/2 : (haopen[1] + haclose[1]) / 2
```

2. To use the security function and avoid the repainting : use the function below with the _repaint parameter to false

```
    f_security_rep(_sym, _res, _src, _repaint = false) => 
        request.security(_sym, _res, _src[not _repaint and barstate.isrealtime ? 1 : 0])[_repaint or barstate.isrealtime ? 0 : 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

So I have added the missing var to the two variables and the recommended security function, also amended to v5 to use `request.security`

I was receiving a "Cannot use a mutable variable as an argument of the security function." which as I understand to be is due to the variables being referenced in the security function

I have added them to a function

```
haclose_func() =>
     var float haclose = 0.
     haclose:= ((open + high + low + close)/4) //[smoothing]

haopen_func() =>
     var float haopen = 0.
     haopen:= na(haopen[1]) ? (open + close)/2 : (haopen[1] + haclose[1]) / 2
```

However I'm receiving 'Mismatched input 'haclose' expecting 'end of line without line continuation' I'm sure the syntax is correct.

So the script looks like this so far:

```
indicator(title="HeikinAshiTriangles", shorttitle="HATriangles", overlay=true)
asa = input(true, title="Show Heikin Ashi Triangles at Top and Bottom of Screen?")
useCurrentRes = input(true, title="Use Current Chart Resolution?")
resCustom = input.timeframe(title="Use Different Timeframe? Uncheck Box Above", defval="60")
res = useCurrentRes ? "" : resCustom

f_security_rep(_sym, _res, _src, _repaint = false) =>
     request.security(_sym, _res, _src[not _repaint and barstate.isrealtime ? 1 : 0])[_repaint or barstate.isrealtime ? 0 : 1]

haclose_func() =>
     var float haclose = 0.
     haclose:= ((open + high + low + close)/4) //[smoothing]

haopen_func() =>
     var float haopen = 0.
     haopen:= na(haopen[1]) ? (open + close)/2 : (haopen[1] + haclose[1]) / 2

heikUp = haclose > haopen
heikDown = haclose <= haopen

hU = f_security_rep(syminfo.tickerid, res, heikUp)
hD = f_security_rep(syminfo.tickerid, res, heikDown)

plotshape(asa and hU ? hU and barstate.isconfirmed: na, title="Heikin Ashi Triangles",style=shape.triangleup, location=location.bottom, color=color.lime)
plotshape(asa and hD ? hD and barstate.isconfirmed: na, title="Heikin Ashi Triangles",style=shape.triangledown, location=location.top, color=color.red)
```

Thanks for your assistance with this.